# org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor missing in Tomcat 10?

Tags: java, tomcat

In my `tomcat/conf/context.xml` I have following:

```
<CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" sameSiteCookies="none"/>
```

After migration to Tomcat 10 (I am using `tomcat:10.1.2-jdk17-temurin` docker image), I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1264)
    ... 58 more
```

However it seems the `LegacyCookieProcessor` is still supported:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/LegacyCookieProcessor.html

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is supported in Tomcat 10.0.x, not in 10.1.x.

`tomcat:10.1.2-jdk17-temurin` is 10.1.x.